# Rails 4.0.4, want checkboxes rendered as checked when item.done == true

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I'm building my todo app as a project for my future portfolio. Currently it lacks many features and is suffering from ludicrously-terrible-code sickness. I intend to polish it and with some luck and tons of skillz perhaps one day it will help me get a job as a junior dev or at least an intern ;-)

Currently I'm engaged in a dirty fight with checkboxes. I want them to be (and stay!) checked if the Item they are connected with has Item.done == true, otherwise they should be unchecked. I tried implementing it in the check_box_tag it self, with conditionally adding the checked="checked" prop if item.done == true, but it failed. The hack I am using right now has a couple flaws:

0) (Very sorry for presenting you with such WET, damp, obscenely MOIST code)
1) it's the epitome of very bad code if I ever saw one
2) it doesn't always work - if you check more then one box in rapid succession, all boxes will all render as empty.
3) it just doesn't seem right, quite honestly

Link to github:
https://github.com/Demoniszcze/todo_app

Link to heroku:
http://murmuring-citadel-7289.herokuapp.com/

_items.html.erb:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <% @items.order('created_at asc').each do |item|%>
            <tr>
                <td><%= check_box_tag "item-#{item.id}", item.id, false, 
                    data: {
                    remote: true,
                    url: url_for(action: :do_item, id: item.id),
                    method: :patch,
                    done: item.done
                    } %>
                </td>
                <td width="300px"><div class="items" id="item-<%= item.id %>"><%= item.content %></div></td>
                <td><%= link_to "delete", item_path(item.id), method: :delete, remote: true %></td>
            </tr>   
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
(function() {
    $('input[data-done="true"]').prop('checked', 'checked');
    $('input[data-done!="true"]').removeAttr('checked');
})();
</script>
```

items_controller.rb:

```
def do_item
    @items = Item.all
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.done 
        if @item.update(done:false)
          format.html { redirect_to :index }
          format.js {}
        else
          format.html { redirect_to :index }
        end


      else

        if @item.update(done:true)
          format.html { redirect_to :index }
          format.js {}
        else
          format.html { redirect_to :index }
        end

      end

    end
  end
```

Yep, using jQuery every-single-friggin-time. God my eyes hurt when I look at this. Please, please, please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Don't know if you tried this already, this might be missing some interaction too, but:)

When I look at the [docs for `check_box_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag), it has a parameter for the `checked` state:

```
check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})
```

Does it work when you use `item.done` as the third parameter?

```
check_box_tag "item-#{item.id}", "1", item.done
```

Comment: It does, indeed! How silly of me to miss this one, I feel ashamed @_@